For what number rings does $N^{1/d}$ form an absolute value?
If $K/\mathbb{Q}$ is a number field of degree $d$ with ring of integers $\mathcal{O}_K$ when is $f:=|N|^{1/d}$ an absolute value on $\mathcal{O}_K$? Here $N$ is the algebraic norm that sends $\xi \in \mathcal{O}_K$ to the product of its $d$ conjugates.
Clearly this satisfies $f(\xi)\geq 0$ with equality only at $\xi = 0$, and since $N$ is multiplicative, $f(\xi_1\cdot \xi_2) = f(\xi_1)f(\xi_2)$. The tricky part is the triangle inequality.
For example, in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$, $f$ is just the regular complex absolute value, and so definitely satisfies the triangle inequality, but in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]$ we have that
$$f(21+2\sqrt{2}) = \sqrt{433} > \sqrt{119}+\sqrt{98} = f(11+\sqrt{2}) + f(10+\sqrt{2})$$
so that the triangle inequality does not hold.
As another (more interesting) example, numerical evidence seems to suggest that $f$ satisfies the triangle inequality when $K = \mathbb{Q}(\zeta_5)$ where $\zeta_5$ is a $5$th root of unity, but I'm unsure how to prove this.

What does numerical evidence mean: you tried some random examples?  Anyway, in the non-archimedean setting, when $p$ is an inert prime in $K$ the function $f(\alpha) = |{\rm N}{K/\mathbf Q}(\alpha)|p^{1/d}$ on $K$ is an absolute value since $(p)$ being the unique prime over $p$ in $K$ makes ${\rm N}{K/\mathbf Q}(\alpha)={\rm N}{K_{(p)}/\mathbf Q_p}(\alpha)$ for $\alpha \in K$, so the absolute value on $K_{(p)}$ extending $\mathbf Q_p$ equals $f$ on the subfield $K$.

Thank you! Yes, I tried $10^7$ random examples with coefficients on the standard basis between $-1000$ and $1000$.

Let $\|x\|:=|N_{K/\mathbf{Q}}(x)|^{1/d}$.
If $K$ is either an imaginary quadratic field or the rational numbers, then $\| \cdot \|$ coinicides with the usual absolute value and so it will be a norm.
If $K$ is not of this form, then $\| \cdot \|$ will never be a norm. To prove this, note that under the assumptions there exists a unit $u \in \mathcal{O}^{\times}_K$ which is not of finite order (Dirichlet's Unit Theorem). Since all powers of $u$ have norm $1$, then $\|u^m\| = 1$ for all integers $m$. So if it was a norm, then, by the triangle inequality,
$$\|1 + u^m\| \le 2$$
But that would mean that $N(1 + u^m) \le 2^d$ for all integers $m$. I now show this can't happen. By Kronecker's theorem, not all conjugates of $u$ can have absolute value $1$, so there is at least one conjugate with absolute value bigger than one. We have
$$N(1 + u^m) = \prod |1 + (\sigma u)^m|$$
It is actually true (but tricky) that $N(1+u^m)$ tends to infinity, but let us just prove the weather claim that there is a sequence of $m$ for which it gets big. If you look at the product, there are three types of term. The first is for conjguates $|\sigma u| > 1$. Clearly as $m$ gets bigger these terms become huge. Then there are terms with $|\sigma u| < 1$, and these terms will tend to $1$ as $m$ gets large. So you only need to worry about the conjugates with $|\sigma u| = 1$. For such conjugates, you can write $\sigma u = e^{2 \pi i \alpha_{\sigma}}$ for some real number $\alpha_{\sigma}$. But now, by Dirichlet's principle, you can find arbitrarily large integers $m$ so that the vector $(m \alpha_{\sigma})$ is very close to a lattice point, that is, $m \alpha_{\sigma}$ is very close to $0 \bmod 1$ for all the relevant $\sigma$. For such $m$, we see that $(\sigma u)^m$ (no absolute values!) is very close to $1$, so the terms inside $N(1+u^m)$ are very close to $2$ in these cases. So for these $m$, $N(1+u^m)$ will clearly be growing without bound.
For your example $K = \mathbf{Q}(\zeta_5)$, we can take the unit
$$u = \zeta + \zeta^{-1} = \frac{\sqrt{5} - 1}{2}$$
Then the norms of $1+u^m$ for $m = 1,2,\ldots$ are
$$1, 25, 16, 81, 121, 400, 841, 2401, 5776, 15625, 39601, 104976, \ldots $$

Very clever to use the unit theorem, thanks!

A different argument that this is an absolute value iff $K$ is imaginary quadratic (or $\Bbb Q$) is as follows. First note that if it is an absolute value, it must be archimedean as it is unbounded on $\Bbb Z$. Let $\hat K$ be the completion of $K$ with respect to $f$. Then $\hat K$ is a complete archimedean field, and one can show that either $\hat K\cong \Bbb R$ or $\Bbb C$ with the usual absolute value. So there is an embedding $\tau:K\to\Bbb C$ such that $f(x)=|\tau(x)|$. By the way this is an important fact: Every archimedean absolute value comes from such an embedding. But we assumed that $f(x)=|N(x)|^{1/d}=|\prod_{\sigma:K\to\Bbb C}\sigma(x)|^{1/d}$. If $K$ is neither $\Bbb Q$ nor imaginary quadratic, there are embeddings $K\to\Bbb C$ which are different from $\tau$ (and its complex conjugate) and it should follow that $f(x)=|\sigma(x)|$ is not possible for all $x$. I am not sure what the quickest way of showing this would be, but one possibility is to show that absolute values induced by embeddings that are not equal or complex conjugates are inequivalent (this is not difficult) and then to appeal to the approximation theorem.
